# How to retrieve the value of RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget: @target?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a ruby method that returns a hash. My Rspec for this method looks like this:

```
require "java"
require "rubygems"
require 'rspec'
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../src/lib/my_class.rb'

describe MyMod::Myclass do
  before(:all){
                @my_obj = MyMod::Myclass.new
              }


it "" do
  expect(@my_obj.get_hash_info(city)).should == {"name"=>"NY", "zip"=>"1234"}
  puts "get_hash_info method test case PASSED"
end
end
```

But it is erroring out by giving the following message:

```
   Failure/Error: expect(@my_obj.get_hash_info(city)).should == {"name"=>"NY", "zip"=>"1234"}

   expected: {"name"=>"NY", "zip"=>"1234"}
        got: #<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x6339e604 @target={"name"=>"NY", "zip"=>"1234"}> (using ==)
   Diff:
   @@ -1,7 +1,9 @@
   -"name"=>"NY",
   -"zip"=>"1234",
   +#<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x6339e604
   + @target=
   +  {"name"=>"NY",
   +   "zip"=>"1234"}>
```

I need help in retrieving the value of `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x6339e604 @target` so that I compare it with the expected hash.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mix expectations with the `should` argument  `expect` creates an expectation target object. `should` is a method monkey patched by `rspec` into all objects in an `it` block.

You can do...

```
@my_obj.get_hash_info(city).should == {"name"=>"NY", "zip"=>"1234"}
```

Or you can do...

```
expect(@my_obj.get_hash_info(city)).to eq {"name"=>"NY", "zip"=>"1234"}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Now it is working fine.